# How to handle a randomly activated thread that has a costant running time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not sure if this is automatically handled by java or am I supposed to handle such an event...

Say I have a method that is invoked externally at a random times, and has a constant running time.
If we say its running time is t, then there might be a case of a burst where the method is called every some t0 that is less than t so the method hasn't finished running and it is already invoked again.
In such a case am I to buffer its requests manually or does java do that for me ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, but the answer could be that you need to run that method in separate threads to prevent several consecutive calls from delaying each other.

Comment: Weird, stackoverflow trimmed my question.

Comment: if the processing is too long, as you seem to suggest, you should consider implementing an error protocol to refuse calls when there's too many of them queued.

Answer (score 2):

Requests to methods are automatically queued UNLESS requests have been issued from separate threads in which case the method will be executed concurrently (in which case you may want to use a concurrency construct - to provide mutually exclusive access, for example).

Comment: Thanks xagyg. Straight to the point.